# sockets irc bot not sending complete message

Tags: python, sockets, irc

I am trying to make an irc bot. It connects but doesn't send the complete message. If I want to send "hello world" it only sends "hello". It just sends everything until the first space.

In this program if you type hello in irc, the bot is supposed to send hello world. But it only sends hello.

```
import socket

channel = "#bots"
server = "chat.freenode.org"
nickname = "my_bot"


class IRC:
    irc = socket.socket()

    def __init__(self):
        self.irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def send(self, chan, msg):
        self.irc.send("PRIVMSG " + chan + " " + msg + "\n")

    def connect(self, server, channel, botnick):
        # defines the socket
        print("connecting to: " + server)
        self.irc.connect((server, 6667))  # connects to the server

        self.irc.send("NICK %s\n" % botnick)
        self.irc.send("USER %s %s Ibot :%s\n" % (botnick, botnick, botnick))
        self.irc.send("JOIN %s\n" % channel)
        self.irc.send("PRIVMSG %s :Hello Master\n" % channel)

    def get_text(self):
        text = self.irc.recv(2040)  # receive the text

        if text.find('PING') != -1:
            self.irc.send('PONG ' + text.split()[1] + 'rn')

        return text

irc = IRC()

irc.connect(server, channel, nickname)

while True:
    text = irc.get_text().strip()

    if "hello" in text.lower():
        irc.send(channel, "hello world")

    print text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a : before the message. This should work:

```
def send(self, chan, msg):
    self.irc.send("PRIVMSG " + chan + " :" + msg + "\n")
```